# Understanding getDay() method when the date object receives parameters

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm fairly new to JS and have been trying to get my head round a section of [this](https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/code/449311/simple-month-calendar) calendar tutorial specifically the initialisation of the day related vars i.e.

```
firstDayOfMonth = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay()
```

and

```
var dow = new Date(y, m, i).getDay();
```

Using the [JS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) my understanding of the above code is as follows:

For:

```
firstDayOfMonth = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay()
```

If y = 2015, m = 3 then firstDayOfMonth should be 0 (Sunday) but I keep getting the 3 (Wednesday).

For

```
var dow = new Date(y, m, i).getDay();
```

Say y = 2015, m = 3 and i = 1 then firstDayOfMonth should be 0 (Sunday) but I keep getting the 3 (Wednesday).

Where could i be going wrong in grasping how the getDay(); method works when parameters are passed to it.

Note: I understand how it works when parameters are not passed to it i.e. say if today's date was 23/05/2015 I understand why the code below returns 1 i.e. a Monday

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getDay();
</script>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Month 3 is April. You want month 2 for March.